# Improved Insertion Method for Linear Probing

Tags: algorithm, hash, time-complexity

Currently, I am asked to devise an *O(n log n)* algorithm for inserting *n* elements into a hash table with *n* slots using linear probing.

Originally, it would take up to *O(n^2)* time for inserting *n* elements, if the hash values generated by the hash function end up being a single number.

Therefore, I am thinking about preventing the collisions before hashing any elements, by predicting them using a certain type of data structure.

For example: calculate all the hash values for each element (which is *O(n)*), search for possible collisions, change the hash values of the colliding keys, and then do insertion.

My question: is it possible to find a data structure that solves my problem in *O(n log n)* time?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, initialize a [vEB tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) to contain 0..n-1, representing the open slots of the hash table. To insert an element into the hash table, call the FindNext method of the vEB tree once or twice (if there is wraparound) to determine the next free slot and then call Delete to remove it from the vEB tree. The total running time is O(n log log n).